# Owing to/Due to difference

Tags: difference

I've been having a struggle since yesterday about when to use *owing to* and *due to*.

Is *owing* old English or not used anymore - because I've never heard it before?

Can you give me some examples when and when not to use them?

Answer (score 1):

They are both current expressions that are used interchangeably; the following extract may help:

> - ***Due to and owing to***  are similar in meaning to ***on account of and because of.*** They are all prepositions used with noun phrases and are often used interchangeably.
> - ***They indicate that something happened as a result of something or introduce the reason for something happening:***
>
>   - *'He was kept in after school due to/owing to his bad behaviour.' = He was kept in after school on account of/because of his bad behaviour.
>       'Due to/owing to a broken propeller, the new cruise liner returned immediately to port.' = 'The new cruise liner returned immediately to port because of/on account of a broken propeller.'*
> - ***It used to be thought that it was incorrect to use due to in this way, but modern usage shows no hesitation in using these expressions interchangeably.***

Also:

> - Note that these prepositions are sometimes used in cleft structures with it and the verb to be:
>
>   - '*It is due to/on account of all his hard work over the winter months that he has passed the exam with such a good grade.'
>       'It was owing to/because of traffic congestion on the road leading to the airport that I missed my flight.'*

<sup>([Source: BBC.com](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv56.shtml))</sup>